# What is the purpose of org.springframework.boot.spring-boot POM?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

What is the purpose of this [POM](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.3.3.RELEASE) in Sprint Boot `org.springframework.boot.spring-boot`

It includes

```
org.springframework.spring-core
org.springframework.spring-context
```

So in something like [org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-starter-web](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.3.3.RELEASE) you have

```
org.springframework.spring-webmvc
org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-starter
org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-starter-json
org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-starter-tomcat
```

Why not just make `org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-starter-web`

```
org.springframework.spring-webmvc
org.springframework.spring-core
org.springframework.spring-context    
org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-starter-json
org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-starter-tomcat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spring-boot-starter` has following dependencies:

```
jakarta.annotation-api
spring-core
spring-boot
spring-boot-autoconfigure
spring-boot-starter-logging
```

if you replace `spring-boot-starter` with `spring-core` and `spring-context`, then you miss out all the classes and annotations that are defined in `spring-boot` and `spring-boot-autoconfigure`(`spring-boot` depends on `spring-core` and `spring-context`, but it has implemented some important classes itself, see below).

take `spring-boot-starter-web` as an example, usually we need to set `server.port` in our `application.yml`, this property is defined in [ServerProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.3.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java#L78) class in `spring-boot-autoconfigure` project(that's why we need `spring-boot-starter` in [org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-starter-web](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.3.3.RELEASE)), there are other commonly used properties such as `server.address`, `server.servlet.context-path`, and `server.ssl.*` ....etc.They are all defined here in `spring-boot-autoconfigure` project.

in order to auto configure the properties defined in [ServerProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.3.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java#L78), class [ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.java#L69) is created to take [ServerProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.3.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java#L78) as a parameter and apply it's values to set up software like [tomcat](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/f50927f7a18d43803da8007871d463a9ab9e6cdf/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/TomcatServletWebServerFactoryCustomizer.java#L34)

now see that [ServerProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.3.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java#L72) is neither annotated with `@Configuration` nor `@Component`, so it wouldn't be instantiated when component-scan is happening, so this annotation [EnableConfigurationProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/221ff0ff6de8bd9557f3fb6d7b336a188b2dd224/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/EnableConfigurationProperties.java#L41) is created to make sure [ServerProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.3.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java#L72)'s instance will be injected. this annotation is defined in `spring boot` project, that's why we need `spring-boot` dependency. And it's used
[here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.java#L64).

for what is a **spring boot starter** and how it works, here is a helpful article: [Quick Guide to Building a Spring Boot Starter](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-starter/)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to understand - what "important dependencies" do you miss? I don't see anything else here https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.pom